# Partitioning hdd

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, gparted

I want to dual boot my laptop with Ubuntu and Windows 8. I have already installed Ubuntu and am trying to partition my hdd for Windows but it wont allow me. I attached a picture of my current hdd setup. The sda5 option and the sda2 option won't let edit it. Does any one know how I can do this?

Comment: Where is the picture?

Comment: Are you trying to edit a mounted partition?

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything you should backup any important files.

You probably cant edit the sda5 and the sda2 partition because they are in use by Ubuntu. You should make a [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) live CD or USB stick and boot to it. You then will be able to edit all of the partitions on your hard-drive. Leave the Ubuntu partition and make a new NTFS partition for Windows. Reboot and remove the Gparted live CD/USB and boot to the Windows 8 setup. Follow the steps and select the partition you made for Windows.

Comment: Sorry, here is the link. http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4731/a30e.png What would cause the red circle next to the sda5 partition? When I click on it, it says "Linux Unified Key Setup encryption is not yet supported" is this bad?

Comment: It appears that you have an [encrypted partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems) on your computer, which is not compatible with Gparted. To resize it you will need an Ubuntu live CD and run some commands in a terminal. You can find more information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions. After you resize the encrypted partition, you should be able to make a NTFS partition for Windows.